# Slide up multiple divs when menu closed

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a menu in JQ that you click a link and it slidetoggles the display of the menu. Within the menu you have direct links to page and then expanding links that show another menu. I have got this working so far:

http://www.eadata.co.uk/testing/test.html#

What i would like to do now is when you click on the link at the top and it toggles back up i need all the expanded menus to be closed. It currently partialy works and just hides the top submenu when toggled. So when you toggle it back down the menus are all closed.

I have been trying to work this out but im still learning JQ. PHP is my thing! :)

Also with this menu is it possible for it to toggle back up after a set time if the mouse has left the menu area?

Comment: First of all i saw your example i think you got already what you want to do :) But in your source i saw a serious problem. You are using same ID in multiple place. ID should be single for an element in entire document. If you want to use it to identify element groups then you can use class or rel etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try this (version ONE):

give all your nav-level-2 a class not a ID (don't forget your CSS).

```
$(".nav-level-2").slideUp('slow');
```

If this don't help, use this:

You can use `$('#nav-container').find('.nav-level-2')` in jQuery to get ALL the elements with this class. With this you can use this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $('#nav-container').find('.nav-level-2').length; i++) {
    $('#nav-container').find('.nav-level-2').eq(i).slideUp('slow');
}
```

If this don't help, use this:

Give all your nav-level-2 unique IDs and store them all in an array and use a for-loop to close ALL levels. if they are closed, they wouldn't animate:

```
var levelarray = new Array('nav-level-2-a', 'nav-level-2-b', 'nav-level-2-c');
for(var i = 0; i < levelarray.length; i++) {
    $('#' + levelarray[i]).slideUp('slow');
}
```

Comment: Thats great! Thanks! Is there anyway that when you clikc on an expanded item it closes other expand items? so only showing one at any one time?

Comment: Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pRgb3/1/ , just added `$(".nav-level-2").slideUp('slow');` to your second function

Comment: Thats fantastic!!! One last thing, Is it possible for the whole menu to disipear after 5 secounds if the mouse has left the nav-container area?

Comment: sure, use this: http://jsfiddle.net/pRgb3/2/ it's now at 3000 ms. Just change this time to increase or decrease the time

Comment: I have just noticed that once you have expanded the menu item and you clikc on it again it closes then imediatly reopens. Is there anyway to make it so that when you click it again it just contracts? Thanks

Comment: sure, use the selector :hidden on `$(this).next('.nav-level-2:hidden').slideToggle(500);` http://jsfiddle.net/pRgb3/3/